# Simplifying an expression involving a complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, logarithms

I asked WolframAlpha to solve a certain differential equation and it gave it in this form: $f(x)=(x-1)(\ln(x-1)-i\pi-1)$.  Now I am only interested in this function when $x$ is in the interval $(0,1)$.  In this case, I think $f(x)$ will always be a real number.

My question is, is there a way to simplify this expression in the interval $(0,1)$, so that it makes no reference to complex logarithms or imaginary numbers?  I just want to express it in terms of real functions.

Comment: Probably not; even if $x$ is real you'll still have that $i\pi$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel But if $x$ is between 0 and 1, then $f(x)$ is a real number.  So you should be able to express one real number in terms of another real number without referring to imaginary numbers.

Comment: What is the differential equation in question, out of curiosity?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer [This one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+q’+%3D+1+-+(q%2F(1-t)),+q(0)%3D1).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer FYI, here is the question that prompted this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3148842/71829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume principal values for the multivalued functions we invoke here. Since $x\in(0,1)$, $x-1$ is negative and
$$\ln(x-1)=\ln(1-x)+i\pi$$
Thus
$$(x-1)(\ln(x-1)-i\pi-1)=(x-1)(\ln(1-x)+i\pi-i\pi-1)=(x-1)(\ln(1-x)-1)$$